# Suppress or Submit record if UI error exists Netsuite Suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Does anyone know how to handle the UI errors in Netsuite Suitescript? I have a script that runs perfectly under normal circumstances. The script loads a sales order and checks a check box then submits the order.  The error I receive is if the customer is on a hold(like a credit hold or slow payment hold) it stops execution of the script, which is bad. Is there a way to handle this either by skipping this particular order(which would be fine) or by submitting the order regardless of that message? I looked in their API but did not see anything that I thought would be useful. I am new to Netsuite and JS so maybe I am not looking for the correct solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too generic I think.  Provide some code for a topical answer.  Generally speaking, you can use the `try{}catch(e){}` paradigm to handle a lot of error situations.  It's likely there's a more elegant solution for your use case however.

Comment: It will mostly depend on *when* this error is thrown. If you are working in say a client or user event script, and the error is thrown by one of your NetSuite API calls, then you should be able to wrap that call in a try-catch and handle/suppress the error accordingly. However, if the error is thrown between two script events, i.e. between *SaveRecord* on the client and *BeforeSubmit* on the user event, or between *BeforeSubmit* and *AfterSubmit* on the user event, then there won't really be any way for you to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it sounds like the error is trying to stop submission of the order when there is a credit hold - this is likely as the result of another user event script.

If you are really sure you want to submit the order regardless of other business scripts you can do `nlapiSubmitRecord(soRec, {disabletriggers:true, enablesourcing:false, ignoremandatoryfields:true});`.

Of course what you have now done is bypassed most scripted checks on the SO. I generally only do this when I am either running some sort of fix/irregular update to backfill fields  or when I am updating a flag that is managed only by my custom functionality. (e.g. on success after queuing a record for transmission to an external system -- this is not a great assumption and I don't generally do this)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a block like:

```
try { trysomething (); }
catch (e) { handle_error(); }
finally { some_default_thing(); }
```

Can handle most unforeseen circumstances. Put your main code under `try`. Then your default, fallback action in the `finally` block, while handling the error conditions in the `catch` block.

Do you have any more details to share?

Comment: Well the error is generated in Netsuite not JS. It is an error stating something about the customer. I will try the above code when I get back home and see if that helps at all.